# How to make Discord Bot react to a message in a channel, if the message contains a facebook link?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

So I want that in a specific channel, where advertising is enabled, when someone pastes in a facebook, or instagram or whatever link, then the bot automatically reacts to that message with the specific logo emote, what the server has.
Is there any way to do this?

I'm thinking about something like this:

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.channel.id == channel.id.here && message.author.bot == false && message.content("facebook")) { addreactions1(message); }
});

function addreactions1(message) {
  if (message.attachments.size === 1) {
    message.react("facebook.logo.emote")
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since <Message>.content returns a String, you can use the [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) method which performs a **case-sensitive** search of one string in another string. Eg:

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if(message.author.bot) return; //returns doesn't respond to bot or webhook messages.
  if(message.channel.id === "channelid"){
    if(message.content.includes("Facebook"){ //searches for Facebook in the message.
      message.channel.send("Message content had Facebook as a word in it"); // do anything here
    }
  }      
}
```